# Bifurcations in two dimensional systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, bifurcation, stability-theory

Given the following autonomous differential equations, which illustrates an elliptic limit cycle,

$r' = \alpha -\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)^2 \cos^2\theta - \left(\frac{r}{b}\right)^2 \sin^2\theta \\
\theta ' = -1$

Where, $r= r(t),\\ \theta = \theta(t),\\ a,b > 0 \\\alpha \quad \text{is a scaling constant, known from the equation of an ellipse as 1}$

Analyzing the system for possible bifurcation, where i startet with finding the Jacobian matrix, which gave the following eigenvalues,

$\lambda_{0} = 0 \\ \lambda_{2}=-\frac{2r\left(\cos^2\theta \cdot b^2+\sin^2\theta\cdot a^2\right)}{a^2b^2}$

I found the fix points for the system, but the size made it difficult to use them in any way.

Where did it go wrong? And are there something that might make this bifurcation analysis ane easier ?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a scaling constant, known from the equation of an ellipse as 1.

Comment: In neighbourhood of what regime are you analyzing? Do you understand that your system doesn't have equilibria?

Comment: I have already found the dependency of the intervals of $\alpha$, for which the circle would have an bifurcation. This is just a special case of the elliptic equation, where $a=b=1$, further i would like to show that the same intervals apply for an ellipse, @Evgeny

Comment: I don't understand what bifurcation are you talking about right now. As I've already said, this system has no equilibria or fixed points.